# The Semi-preopen set

Tags: general-topology

**Theorem:** Let$(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $A\subset X$:

1:for every open set $G$, We have $‎‎cl(A)‎\cap ‎G‎‎\subset‎ cl(A\cap G)‎‎$‎‎‎.

2:for every close set $F$, We have ‎‎$‎int(A‎\cup F)‎\subset int(A) ‎\cup F‎‎‎‎$‎.

**Definition:** Let$(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $A\subset X$. The set $A$ is called semi-preopen if ‎$‎A‎\subset cl(int(cl(A)))‎$‎.‎ The set of all semi-preopen sets in the space $X$ is denote by $SPO(X,\tau)$.

**Question:**
Let  ‎‎$‎Y\in SPO(X,\tau)‎$ ‎and ‎‎$‎G\in\tau‎‎‎$‎. Is $‎Y‎\cap ‎cl_{X}(G)‎‎‎ ‎\subset ‎cl_{X}(Y‎\cap ‎G)‎$‎‎right?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.